# Is there a way to import JSON file into dexie js?

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, dexie

I am using dexie js which has a import db method for importing large json files. The problem is it is only for dexis db files. I need to be able to basically do bulk add but with this json file as it is too large to import it into memory.